# waveshare 3.2" LCD touchscreen touch functionality stopped working

Tags: gpio, python, serial, touchscreen, pi-zero-w

I'm using [this](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.2inch_RPi_LCD_(B)#Driver) touchscreen on a raspi zero w and I'm currently working on a python application.

I was working with the python serial module since some time and everything was working fine, but since some days when I try to work with the serial module, the touchscreen functionality vanishes, first 30 seconds it ignores like 70% of touches and after that it just stops working.

Here is a interesting part of the dmesg output, but I couldn't find out if there is any useful information:

```
[   15.057964] ads7846 spi0.1: touchscreen, irq 177
[   15.073211] input: ADS7846 Touchscreen as /devices/platform/soc/20204000.spi/spi_master/spi0/spi0.1/input/input0
[   15.111258] fbtft: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   15.161098] fb_ili9340: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   15.162101] pinctrl-bcm2835 20200000.gpio: pin gpio17 already requested by spi0.1; cannot claim for spi0.0
[   15.162132] pinctrl-bcm2835 20200000.gpio: pin-17 (spi0.0) status -22
[   15.162151] pinctrl-bcm2835 20200000.gpio: could not request pin 17 (gpio17) from group gpio17  on device pinctrl-bcm2835
[   15.162163] fb_ili9340 spi0.0: Error applying setting, reverse things back
[   15.162246] fbtft_of_value: buswidth = 8
[   15.162264] fbtft_of_value: debug = 0
[   15.162274] fbtft_of_value: rotate = 180
[   15.162285] fbtft_of_value: fps = 25
[   16.259374] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
```

Comment: It looks like you have a conflict on pin 17

Comment: I see that, but I don't know how to find out where the conflict comes from or how to resolve it

Comment: What else is connected to the GPIO pins?

Comment: Well the raspi board itself is connected to another board via gpios which provides watchdog functionality, a uart serial and power supply.
That board also has gpios which are connected to the display

Comment: Btw: I tested it with a new display (same model) and got the same results, I had backup images from previous development stages and none of them worked, so I think by now that the board between raspi and touchscreen might be the issue